# FastCGI PHP7.2 always timeouts Nginx Bash ubuntu on Windows

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to install PHP7.2 and Nginx on my development machine. My development machine is running on Bash Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows.

I've had a working Nginx and PHP7.0 installed before deleting previous versions of PHP and installing PHP7.2.

Error.log output:

```
2017/12/07 03:30:33 [error] 32655#32655: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /helloworld.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

php7.2-fpm.log:

```
[07-Dec-2017 03:29:29] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[07-Dec-2017 03:29:29] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[07-Dec-2017 03:29:30] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 32683
[07-Dec-2017 03:29:30] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[07-Dec-2017 03:29:30] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

sites-available/default:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

The page I'm trying to load:

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

I've tried completely removing all PHP7* and Nginx and re-installing with fresh config files but same result.

If I create a page with phpinfo() it does display all information but it keeps loading.

I don't know where to begin as there are no proper errors appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, problem was that WSL doesn't support unix:socket and required me to comment out:

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/home/{user}/.valet/valet.sock;
```

and add

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

and do the same on

> /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf